# forEach() fire first until it's finished after that, firebase works

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm working with angular, angular material and firebase.
I found this issue while I was debugging.

> Expected

What I expected was the item of forEach goes into the `searchCategory` method and execute `this.categorySubscription = this.storeService.doc$(`path`).subscribe();`

**However, now in my code, forEach works until it's done after that, firestore subscribe executes.**

So, it's the component that when a user adds a category, if there is no category in the server, distinguish a new category. Otherwise, it distinguishes the category user added as already exist.

> Process

The process is that, first, categories are put into the category list and it works with forEach. When the first category goes into the searchCategory method and searches the category on the server using firestore query.
In subscribe, we could get a data that if it's null - means no category on the server - or not. So, if the data is null then I'll use add query, other wise, use update query.

If you give any advice or tips, it could be very helpful. Thank you.

Here's my codes

```js
this.storeInfo.value['categoryChips'].forEach(category => {
      this.searchCategory(category);
}
```

//...

```js
searchCategory(category) {
   this.categorySubscription = this.storeService.doc$(`categories/${category.name}`).subscribe(
  data => {
    if (data === null || data === undefined) {
      // add a new category

      this.addCategory(category);
      this.getRelStore(category.name);
    }
      else {
      // update          
      // this.test2(category, path, data['id']);
      // this.categorySubscription.unsubscribe();
      // this.categoryNum++;
      // this.getRelStore(category.name);
    }
  }
);
}

//...
```

```js
//get related stores as an array
  getRelStore(name) {
    this.categorySubscription.unsubscribe();
    this.loadRel = this.storeService.doc$(`categories/${name}/relatedStore/store`).subscribe(
  data => {

    // there's no related store.
    if (data !== null && data !== undefined) {
      let tempRelatedStores;
      tempRelatedStores = data['name'];
      tempRelatedStores.push(this.storeName);
      this.addRelStore(name, tempRelatedStores);
    } else { // there are related stores already
      this.storeService.set(`categories/${name}/relatedStore/store`, {
        name: this.storeName
      });
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved with `.take(1)`.
I add `.take(1)` in front of `subscribe()`.
It sends one item what I was expected.